# Swift - UIAlert doesn't work in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am coding without storyboard and I'm having this issue now that I can't find a good solution.

So I'm trying to call `UIAlert` from `UICollectionViewCell` like below.

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is what I found in stackoverflow and it works.

But when the `ViewController` which has the `UICollectionViewCell` is presented from the other `ViewController` by  `present(_:animated:completion:)` like below, `UIAlert` doesn't get called.

```
self.present(HomeController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Does anyone know the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your cell is responsible for presenting an alert controller is not a good design, The `cell` should delegate this. Having said that, it is possible to get the view controller where the `cell` is in and present the alert controller using it:

```
extension UIView {
    var parentController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And in the place where you'd like to present the controller from the cell:

```
if let vc = cell.parentController {
    vc.present(// alert controller)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that will not work you need to implement delegate for that if you want to show alert on tapping action from cell

```
 protocol CollectionViewCellDelegate: class {
    func showAlert(_ cell: CollectionViewCell, _ message: String)
 }

 class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
    ....
    .....

    weak var delegate: CollectionViewCellDelegate?

   @IBAction func yourButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
       self.delegate?.showAlert(self, "your message")
   }
}
```

in your viewController

the collection's `cellforRow`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = collectioView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

     ....
     cell.delegate = self
     return cell
}
```

conform to delegate like

```
   extension YourClass: CollectionViewCellDelegate {

    func showAlert(_ cell: CollectionViewCell, _ message: String) {

       let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message: "Alert Message", style = .alert)
       alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "title", style: .default, handler: nil)
       self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only present from the top most view controller. I assume you are trying to present alert controller from `rootViewController`. That will not work if another `viewController` has been presented over it already. Which in your case is `HomeController`.

Present it over the `HomeController` using `self.present()` call. Not over the `rootViewController`